# Как сделать карту и систему координат для неё на python

Tags: python

Объясняю что именно я имел ввиду. Я делаю игру на питоне и мне нужна была карта, я её сделал но работает она не так как хотелось. Мне нужно чтобы в начале (в верхнем левом углу) появлялся персонаж и после им можно было управлять. А смысл игры примерно такой: персонаж появляется после ему нужно пройти до выхода, но на пути ему встречаются либо ловушки либо бонусы, (бонусы и ловушки уже сделаны и они уже рандомно выбираются), нужно только это всё применить к карте, а как я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Вот код карты:

```
#Создаём вход и выход
enter = ''
exit = ''
#Создаём карту
map = [
['■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'], 
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■'],
['  ■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■', '■']
]
#Выводим всё на экран
def mapa():
    global x, y
    print(enter, end='')
    for i in map[0]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[0][9]:
        print(map[0][9])
    for i in map[1]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[1][9]:
        print(map[1][9])
    for i in map[2]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[2][9]:
        print(map[2][9])
    for i in map[3]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[3][9]:
        print(map[3][9])
    for i in map[4]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[4][9]:
        print(map[4][9])
    for i in map[5]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[5][9]:
        print(map[5][9])
    for i in map[6]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[6][9]:
        print(map[6][9])
    for i in map[7]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[7][9]:
        print(map[7][9])
    for i in map[8]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[8][9]:
        print(map[8][9])
    for i in map[9]:
        print(i, end='')
    if i == map[9][9]:
        print(map[9][9], end='')
    print(exit)
mapa()
```

Вот код персонажа:

```
#Импортируем карту
from map import*
#Создаём персонажа и ставим его
character = '‍♂️'
map.pop([0][0])
map.append(character)
#Устанавливаем здоровье и жизни
xp = 100
lives = 3
#Делаем x и y координаты
x = 0
y = 0
map[y][x]
#Управление
print('Управление:\n/w - Вверх\n/s - Вниз\n/a - Влево\n/d - Вправо')
choice = ''
while len(choice.strip()) < 1:
    choice = input('Ваш ход:/')
if choice == 'w':
    if y == 0:
        print('Туда нельзя походить')
    else:
        y += 1
        mapa()
elif choice == 's':
    if y == 9:
        print('Туда нельзя походить')
    else:
        y -= 1
        mapa()
elif choice == 'a':
    if x == 0:
        print('Туда нельзя походить')
    else:
        x -= 1
        mapa()
elif choice == 'd':
    if x == 9:
        print('Туда нельзя походить')
    else:
        x += 1
        mapa()
else:
    print('Команда не распознана повторите попытку')
```

И вот код бонусов и ловушек:

```
#Импортируем нужные модули
import time
import random
#Устанавливаем здоровье, жизни и координаты
xp = 100
lives = 3
x = 0
y = 0
#Рандомный выбор блока
def funcs():
     if True :
        f = [bad_funcs, good_funcs]
        rand_func = random.choice(f)
        rand_func()
#Блоки с уроном
def bad_funcs():
     if True :
        f = [bomb, poison, down, wind, radiation]
        rand_func = random.choice(f)
        rand_func()
def bomb():
    global nxp
    print('')
    nxp = xp - 50
    time.sleep(1)
    print('')
    return nxp
def poison():
    global nxp
    print(' ')
    nxp = xp - 30
    return nxp
def poisondinamoxp():
    global nxp
    nxp = xp - 40
    for i in range(xp, nxp, -10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return nxp
def down():
    global nxp
    print('⚠️')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('■')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('⚠️')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('■')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('⚠️')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('')
    nxp = xp - 100
    return nxp
def wind():
    global nxp
    print('')
    nxp = xp - 10
    return nxp
def radiation():
    global nxp
    print('☣')
    nxp = xp - 60
def radiationdinamoxp():
    global nxp
    for i in range(xp, nxp, -10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return nxp
#Блоки с бонусами
def good_funcs():
     if True :
        f = [apteka, live, helicopter, teleport, eyes]
        rand_func = random.choice(f)
        rand_func()
def apteka():
    global nxp
    print('')
    nxp = xp + 20
    return nxp
def live():
    global nlive
    print('❤')
    nlive = lives + 1
    return nlive
def helicopter():
    global x, y
    print('')
    nxp = xp + 0
    return x, y
def teleport():
    global x, y
    print('☸')
    return x, y
def eyes():
    global x, y
    print('')
funcs()
```

(P.S коментарии здесь не потому что я брал куски кода с интернета, а потому что я сам их ставил для своего приятеля)

Comment: Персонажа и все двигающиеся объекты не вставляйте в карту, а рисуйте "поверх" нее.

Comment: @insolor подскажите пожалуйста как именно это реализовать?

Comment: Проще всего взять colorama. Через нее с помощью `Cursor.POS(x, y)` ставите курсор на нужное место (допустим, левый верхний край экрана), от этого места рисуете карту. Потом смотрите позицию вашего персонажа, ставите курсор на эту позицию, рисуете его. При перерисовке карты опять ставите курсор в левый верхний угол экрана, рисуете карту поверх старой карты, потом рисуете персонажа.

Comment: Вот тут есть пример использования Cursor.POS, правда зачем-то сделано через промежуточную лямбду с перестановкой x и y (видимо автору примера было так удобнее): https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/demos/demo06.py